# How to fill cell with a running value until I meet a new number and calculate the sum?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a lot of rows in excel and now I found that I need to calculate the rolling sum on each row.
I am probably not explaining this well, I will post a picture:
[image]

Basically I have a lot of rows with different values across columns. I need to fill the empty cells (on each row) with the "current" value, until it meets a new number. When that happens, make the sum, overwrite the cell value with the sum, and carry on in the empty cells.

Above in the picture, first row is what I currently have, the other row is what I need.

I have absolutely 0 ideas how to go about this, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row you want the value of is row 1, then the below equation should work. Paste it into column A of the row that you want to have the running total, then drag it across the row as far as you want it to calculate.

Cheers!

=sum(indirect("A1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,column(),4),1,"")&"1"))

Comment: How do I add this to a blank workbook ? I want this formula applied to all the rows, and whenever I add data into cells it automatically does this ?